# Create laravel in resource route

Tags: php, laravel, resources

i dev function and blade for create `Mission`, but when i click on "Ajouter Mission", Nothing happens…

where is the problem please ?

controller :

```
 public function create($request, $id)
    {
        $miss = \App\User::find($id);
       $mission = new Mission;
       $mission->NOM =$request->input('NOM');
       $mission->ID_PERSONNELS = $miss->ID_PERSONNELS;
       $mission->ID_NOTE_DE_FRAIS = 1;
       $mission->DATE_MISSION = $request->input('DATE_MISSION');
       $mission->save();
    }
```

and my blade file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                    @csrf
                    You are in home as Admin !

                    </br>
                    Liste des Utilisateurs
                    <table class="table table-sstriped card-body">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Numero Matricule</th>
                                <th>Nom</th>
                                <th>Prenom</th>
                                <th>Rue</th>
                                <th>Code Postal</th>
                                <th>Ville</th>
                                <th>Adresse mail</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($users as $resp)

                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$resp->MATRICULE}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->NOM}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->PRENOM}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->RUE}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->CP}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->VILLE}}</td>
                                <td>{{$resp->email}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <form action="{{action('UserController@destroy', $resp['ID_PERSONNELS'])}}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Supprimer</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                                        Ajouter Mission
                                    </button>

                                    <!-- Modal -->
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ajouter une Mission</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body  justify-content-center">
                                                    <!----------------------------------Body---------------------------------------------->
                                                    <label for="NOM" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center">{{ __('NOM') }}</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <input id="NOM" type="text" class="form-control @error('NOM') is-invalid @enderror" name="NOM" required autocomplete="NOM" autofocus> @error('NOM')
                                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                        </span> @enderror

                                                    </div>


                                                    <label for="DATE_MISSION" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center">{{ __('DATE_MISSION') }}</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                                        <input id="DATE_MISSION" type="date" class="form-control @error('DATE_MISSION') is-invalid @enderror" name="DATE_MISSION" required autocomplete="DATE_MISSION" autofocus> @error('DATE_MISSION')
                                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                        </span> @enderror

                                                    </div>

                                                  <!--   <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center" for="ID_PRATICIEN">{{ __('PRATICIEN') }}</label> -->

                                                    <!--  <select class="custom-select col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                                                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                    <option value="1">One</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                                                </select>    -->
                                                    <!--------------------------------End----Body------------------------------------>


                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
                                                    <button type="submit" href="{{route('mission.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter Mission</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </td>



                            </tr>
                        </tbody> @endforeach
                </div>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection @csrf
```

Thanks !

Comment: what you have mentioned route in routes.php file

Comment: Route::resource('mission', 'MissionController');

Comment: you are using ajax to send data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you need to update your code here. you need to create the form and use submit button then.

```
<form action="{{route('mission.create')}}" method="post">

@csrf
<!----------------------------------Body---------------------------------------------->
    <label for="NOM" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center">{{ __('NOM') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="NOM" type="text" class="form-control @error('NOM') is-invalid @enderror" name="NOM" required
               autocomplete="NOM" autofocus> 
        @error('NOM')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

    <label for="DATE_MISSION" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center">{{ __('DATE_MISSION') }}</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="DATE_MISSION" type="date" class="form-control @error('DATE_MISSION') is-invalid @enderror"
               name="DATE_MISSION" required autocomplete="DATE_MISSION" autofocus> 
        @error('DATE_MISSION')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>

<!--   <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center" for="ID_PRATICIEN">{{ __('PRATICIEN') }}</label> -->

    <!--  <select class="custom-select col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-center" id="inputGroupSelect01">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>    -->
    <!--------------------------------End----Body------------------------------------>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter Mission</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if you are using ajax then you need to use input type button instead of submit and send the data using ajax

Comment: Yep, something happens now, Wtf, i didn't know i was using Ajax